# plot a rational function with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am trying to plot a function but something is incorrectly written...
Could anyone please help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (10,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,10) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[dotted] (1.4,3.33) -- (1.4,0);
\draw[dotted] (0,3.33) -- (1.4,3.33)  node[left = 0.65cm] {$\frac{10}{3}$};
\draw [domain=0.1:10] plot (\x,{2/(\x-0.8)}) node[right] {$f(x)=\frac{10}{5x-4}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please upload a complete example, i.e. with class declaration and everything necessary for it to be executed "out of the box".

Comment: You are dividing by zero at `\x=0.8`

Comment: What is problem? Please explain in some details.

Comment: I think this is not correctly write: plot (\x,{2/(\x-0.8)})

Comment: yes @JBantje you are right! But should I change the domain? [domain=0.1:10] did not worked!

Comment: I would separate it in two graphs : one with [domain = 0.1:0.7] and the other with [domain = 0.9:10] (or something like that).

Comment: Separating the plot into two is the only way, to get this working with the simple `plot` command. With 'pgfplots` however there are ways to get this done as @percusse demonstrated in his answer. If you are going to use more plots in the future, I recommend reading the manual of `pgfplots`, it is really powerful, but it takes some time to get used to it.

Answer (score 7):

Use `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:5,samples=150,
restrict y to domain=-10:10,
xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
extra x ticks={0.8,1.4},
extra y ticks=3.333333,extra y tick labels={$\frac{10}{3}$},
grid=both,axis lines=middle
]
\addplot+[no marks] {2/(x-0.8)} node[above left] {$f(x)=\frac{10}{5x-4}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot @percusse, but why I got this message?
! Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.11' unknown in choice key '/pgfplots/compat/

Comment: @PauloSousa You need to update your package then. Current version 1.11 but probably you have an older one

Comment: Probably, because your `pgfplots` is not up to date. Update it via the management tools of your TeX-Distribution.

Comment: @PauloSousa the example of percusse will also work if you write `compat=1.10` or (probably) `compat=1.9`. This key ensures that graphics remain compatible even if new releases of `pgfplots` change something.

Comment: compat=1.10 worked fine